# ¿cómo refrescar una página con php?

Tags: php

quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de refrescar la página con php de una forma que no sea con el location.

Porque por el momento no he podido encontrar otra forma

Comment: ¿Puedo preguntar por qué no lo quieres hacer con el `location`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De hecho creo que solo `header`esta definido para este propósito, cuando tienes:

```
header("Location: URL");
```

> ..."Location:" No solamente envía el encabezado al navegador, sino que
>   también devuelve el código de status (302) REDIRECT al navegador a no
>   ser que el código de status 201 o 3xx ya haya sido enviado.

Tal cual lo describen en el sitio oficial: http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php

Un aspecto importante a considerar es que debes evitar salidas previo a la ejecución de esta sentencia, dado que cosas como estas podrían generar problemas:

**Ejemplo 1:** una salida común.

```
<div>contenido antes del header</div>
<?php
header("Location: URL");
```

**Ejemplo 2:** Cualquier salida, incluso un salto de linea

```
·
<?php
header("Location: URL");
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que si bien esto se puede solucionar parcialmente con con ob_start como se indica aquí http://php.net/manual/es/function.ob-start.php

> Esta función activará el almacenamiento en búfer de la salida.
>   Mientras dicho almacenamiento esté activo, no se enviará ninguna
>   salida desde el script (aparte de cabeceras); en su lugar la salida se
>   almacenará en un búfer interno.

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  echo "A partir de ob_start ninguna salida es mostrada directamente
      Son almacenadas en el buffer y por tanto podemos ejecutar header
      sin ninguna preocupación.";
  header("Location: http://php.net/manual/es/function.ob-start.php");
?>
```

Si bien lo anterior funciona, el fragmento a continuación no lo hará:

```
Está salida no debió existir, incluso un salto de linea aquí puede ser peligroso
<?php
  ob_start();
  header("Location: http://php.net/manual/es/function.ob-start.php");
?>
```

usted podrá encontrar entretenido [este articulo](http://programandolo.blogspot.com.co/2013/07/redireccionamiento-php.html) sobre el tema.

Otra opción es generar una pagina temporal que realice la tarea «esto seria útil para dar respiro al servidor en ejecuciones demasiado largas, puesto que es en el cliente donde se dispara la redireccion»

Como alternativa para redireccionar tu pagina puedes usar la etiqueta meta, así:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="TIEMPO;url=URL">
```

donde:

- TIEMPO: es la cantidad de segundos que deben transcurrir hasta que se se haga efectiva la redirección.
- URL: es la dirección web a donde quieres que el usuario sea redirigido.

Una opción extra es usar javascript, como mencione anteriormente estas alternativas puedes servir si deseas mostrar una pagina transitoria «Como aquellas con el mensaje, "Se esta redirigiendo al sitio ..."».

Comment: pero esa no seria una etiqueta de html?

Comment: Si, de hecho por eso lo menciono como alternativa, dado que PHP es un lenguaje con el que construyes HTML puedes generar una pagina que realice esta tarea por ti y de paso decorarla, informando al usuario de la accion que estar por realizar «Se usa mucho de hecho».

Comment: _Un aspecto importante a considerar es que debes evitar salidas previo a la ejecución de esta sentencia, dado que cosas como estas podrían generar problemas:_ Para evitar esto, puedes usar [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ob-start.php) para controlar el buffer de salida.

Answer (score 4):

Sí hay una manera:

```
$archivoActual = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
header("refresh:1;url=" + $archivoActual +"));
```

El parametro que recibe refresh es tiempo en segundos, así que si colocaras no se 15 la página no se redireccionaría hasta pasar 15s desde que se ejecuta el php.

```
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF´];
```

Lo que hace la linea de arriba es obtener la ruta del archivo actual de esa forma no necesitas colocoar una url especifica si es que vas a usar ese mismo código en diferentes páginas, pero si de todas formas quieres colocar una url diferente puedes colocarla, solo sustituye lo que hay después de url por la ruta que quieras.

Saludos!

Comment: Realmente esta es la única respuesta que "refresca" el navegador. Upvote!

Comment: Gracias Muriano!

Answer (score 1):

Te puede servir:

```
header("location:pagina.php");
```

Esto lo que hace, es que te redirecciona a `pagina.php` cuando llega a esa linea de código **php**.

Comment: Es que si me serviria pero el problema es que estoy haciendo una red social entonces digamos si estoy en tu perfil y doy like me manda a mi perfil por este código

Comment: header('location:perfil.php?CodUsua=' . $_SESSION['CodUsua']);

Comment: Lo q quieres es pasar parametros a la url al redireccionar, ¿no?

Comment: Si eso ... y en la url sale el id del usuario ... y quiero tomar ese id para sustituir el $_SESSION['CodUsua'] por $_GET['CodUsua'] ... o cómo crees que seria mejor?

Comment: pasa `header('location:perfil.php?CodUsua='.CodUsua.');` en el archivo `perfil.php` obtienes la variable `$CodUsua` y guardas en `$_SESSION['CodUsua']`

Answer (score 1):

Estas son otras formas de re-dirección:

Opcion 1:

```
$url='tu/url';
echo '<meta http-equiv=refresh content="1; '.$url.'">';
die;
```

Opcion 2:

```
die('<script type="text/javascript">window.location=\''.$url.'\';</script‌​>');
```